# How to change focal point of zoom from center of image to mean value of two touches in hammer.js

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am using hammer.js for zooming image via touches. Its zooming perfectly but i am unable to get its focal point. I mean when i zoom in and zoom out any image then its zoom in perfectly but i am getting that focus is on the center of image, even my both touches in a corner of the image. I want to change its focal point from center of image to mean value of both touches.

here is its hammer variable as defined its example:

```
 hammertime.on('touch drag transform', function(ev) {
    switch(ev.type) {
      case 'touch':
      last_scale = scale;
      last_rotation = rotation;
      break;

      case 'drag':
      posX = ev.gesture.deltaX;
      posY = ev.gesture.deltaY;
      break;

      case 'transform':
      if (event.gesture.scale != 1) {
      rotation = last_rotation + ev.gesture.rotation;
      scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(last_scale * ev.gesture.scale, 10));
      }
      break;
  }
```

refrence link: https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/examples/pinchzoom.html

Edit Code for understanding :

```
 hammertime.on('touch drag dragend transform', function(ev) {
switch(ev.type) {
  case 'touch':
  last_scale = scale;
  last_rotation = rotation;
  break;

  case 'drag':
  possx = posXi + ev.gesture.deltaX;
  possy = posYi + ev.gesture.deltaY;

  break;

  case 'dragend':
  posXi = possx;
  posYi = possy;
  break;

  case 'transform':
  //console.log(ev);
  scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(last_scale * ev.gesture.scale, 10));
    zoom_per = scale*10;
    console.log(zoom_per);
  //zoom_to_size(zoom_percen);
  showLayer(zoom_per);
  break;
}
var transform =
"translate(" + possx + "px," + possy + "px) " +
"scale(" + scale + "," + scale + ") " ;

rect.style.transform = transform;
rect.style.oTransform = transform;
rect.style.msTransform = transform;
rect.style.mozTransform = transform;
rect.style.webkitTransform = transform;
rect.style.webkitTransformOrigin = ev.gesture.center.pageX+'px '+ ev.gesture.center.pageY +'px';
rect.style.transformOrigin = ev.gesture.center.pageX+'px '+ ev.gesture.center.pageY +'px';
```

})

Comment: Hi, did you get this working with the latest HammerJS?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest locating the center of the gesture and assign a new transform-origin to the image. Try adding the following at line 100 of the example. It should point you in the right direction.

```
rect.style.webkitTransformOrigin = ev.gesture.center.pageX+'px '+ ev.gesture.center.pageY +'px';
rect.style.transformOrigin = ev.gesture.center.pageX+'px '+ ev.gesture.center.pageY +'px';
```

Comment: Great, its working perfect in this case... But in my other case when i am also using drag then in that case drag feels some fight. try this code for understanding :

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't quite understand "drag feels some fight" and can't reproduce that behavior. Let me suggest that you move the two lines I gave under **case 'touch'**. This will cause the origin to only be set at the beginning of the gesture. That might stop/limit the drag fight you're experiencing.